# Is there a way to use number format for Summary Fields extension

Tags: summaryfields

The Summary Fields extension is storing results as Money fields which are text format.  This prevents them from being used to filter as numerics in Views and other places.

Is there a way to have the fields created as number fields?

Upon further examination, the field appears to be correct in the MySQL database yet both Drupal Views and Search Builder do not handle the fields correctly.  Views filters think it is a text field.  Search builder queries show incorrect boolean behaviors.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I am having the same problem?

Comment: No, but still interested.  Maybe its a bounty opportunity

Comment: This isn't a good answer so i'll post it as a comment in case anyone needs this quickly... If the ultimate goal is to filter in views as a number field.. text filter handler is default so somewhere it needs to be overridden. Can be done quickly in a module as per the third code example here: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7.x-3.x. May also need to put your module at the end of the list to act after civicrm (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x)